# Realtime currency webservice

Tags: web-services, currency, rate

Anyone know of a real-time currency rate webservice with frequent update (multiple pr. min.). Needed for a small android app I'm building, so needs to be free.

Comment: You can discover how to implement your own currency rate service with black jack and other stuff ;) (http://developersblog.tk/currency-rate-manager-csh-wcf-wpf-mvvm/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try Yahoo. It is free and easy to use.

For example, to convert from GBP to EUR: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv

gives you data in csv format which can easily be parsed.

Comment: Excellent! The Yahoo service provides real-time rates!

Comment: This is not really free. [Read Robyns post](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Using-Yahoo-Finance-API-Not-RSS-/1250246255000-0b82f8f0-7f48-3af2-8fe2-e73a138cbfaa)

Comment: @cocoafan :
The link you have provide is not working i want to know why it is not free and how ?

Comment: unfortunatelly, Yahoo shutted it down.

Answer (score 25):

I would recommend European Central Bank. They provide a daily xml feed, nice and simple.

http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Comment: Excellent input, thank you.This deserves to be an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried with http://openexchangerates.org ?

You can use it's [The Forever Free Plan](https://openexchangerates.org/signup/free) with following features provided.

> - Hourly rate updates
> - Daily historical data
> - 1,000 API requests per month

Comment: This is not free.

Comment: No, there is a free plan

Comment: No it's not. They offer three options and no one is for free.

Comment: Yes its free. They offer three options plus: We also have a Forever Free plan (hourly updates, 1000 requests/month - no HTTPS, email support or advanced features)

Comment: it has free plan which is very limited. For example, you can't change base currency and it always stays USD. Also you can't use other APIs like timeseries etc. But for simple purposes it works.

Answer (score 0):

Real time financial services are usually not available for free. You will find a lot of delayed services ( tipically 15 min ) for free, but you have to make sure licensing allow you to use it in your own application as well.

Comment: I'll check up on licensing. However this is just an app for learning purposes.

Comment: so the seeingidog reply is the one to go for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have some webs where you can take this information. The problem... usually you need pay for this service. Same examples :

- http://www.xignite.com
- http://fxtrade.oanda.co.uk/trade-forex/api/
- http://forex-automatic-trading-systems.com/developers/api.htm
- http://forexfeed.net/developer/php-forex-data-feed-api

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Mondor's web service, especially the WebAPI one. Not free, but could be about 5$ per year, depending from your architecture. Anyway, here's the link: http://mondor.org

Edit: apparently, they have free keys now, or I missed them previously.