# How to get the Latest Currency Exchange Rate in your Asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the Latest Currency Exchange Rate in your Asp.net Application.Is there any build-in API for getting the latest exchange rates from the web.

Requirement:

The Requirement is i have one calculated value in Indian Rupee, on selected Currency from a dropdownlist the value should change.

For example if i select USD from dropdownlist the Calculated value should converted to USD.
For this i want to use some WebService to get the latest Exchange Rates from the Web.

OnselectedIndexchange event of dropdownlist i want to call the webservice to get data for different World Currencies.

Comment: Duplicate of [Realtime currency webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873873/realtime-currency-webservice)

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'build-in' api.

You need to find the provider of such data.

You might want to start with https://openexchangerates.org/

Answer (score 1):

Hi Everyone i got the solution for the above Question.

GO to http://webservicex.net, this is providing a WebService for ExchangeRate

Here is the code what i did.

Add service Reference in your Client Application

[CurrencyConvertor WebService](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx)

Then Create the proxy Object in your Client Application

```
CurrencyExchange.CurrencyConvertor exchangerate = new CurrencyExchange.CurrencyConvertor();
double exchangevalue;
if (DropDownListcurrencies.SelectedValue == "UAE Dhiram")
{
exchangevalue = exchangerate.ConversionRate(CurrencyExchange.Currency.INR,CurrencyExchange.Currency.AED);
resultuae = result * Convert.ToDecimal(exchangevalue);
}
```

Comment: Try this solution.http://codecanyon.net/item/currency-converter/16408544 . It is a paid solution but supports 156 world currencies and real time rates from yahoo finance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into the .NET Framework for getting exchange rates, but you might want to look at a previous StackOverflow question [Are there any free foreign exchangex rate web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898650/are-there-any-free-foreign-exchangex-rate-web-services)