# Plist values are replaced instead of added

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

**hi i have to add  some data to plist in **following format** like in below image**
[image: actual i want]

**but the actual iam getting is like here**

[image: currently wat iam getting]
**please help my code for this is ..**

```
-(void)updatePlist
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pathOfPricePlist= [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Price.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *finalList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[sharedManager.bookidList count];i++) {

        [mutableDictionary setValue:[sharedManager.sharedProductPrice objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"price"];
        [mutableDictionary setValue:[sharedManager.bookidList objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"booknumber"];

        NSLog(@"%@",mutableDictionary);
        [finalList addObject:mutableDictionary];
        NSLog(@"%@",finalList);
    }

    [finalList writeToFile:pathOfPricePlist atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new mutableDictionary on each step of the for loop. Like this:

```
-(void)updatePlist
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pathOfPricePlist= [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Price.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *finalList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[sharedManager.bookidList count];i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


        [mutableDictionary setValue:[sharedManager.sharedProductPrice objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"price"];
        [mutableDictionary setValue:[sharedManager.bookidList objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"booknumber"];

        NSLog(@"%@",mutableDictionary);
        [finalList addObject:mutableDictionary];
        NSLog(@"%@",finalList);
    }

    [finalList writeToFile:pathOfPricePlist atomically:YES];

}
```

Otherwise you simply add the same dictionary over and over again in that array.

Comment: :super boss. You are the man.one doubt if we create a dictionary inside for loop it will use more memory right?

Comment: Yes it will, but I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you have really big plist files. Once you write the plist to the file, all the memory you allocated will be reclaimed. I would suggest using `NSDictionary` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`, and use `+ (id)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys`  to create it in one shot. This is because you already know the number of keys and the values in it.

Comment: i have plist with 150 entries

Comment: Then I don't think it's not a problem using dictionaries

Comment: ok.thanks   do u know how can i convert a currency like $10  to INR 590   ??

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question and there are similar questions here on SO. Here is one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873873/realtime-currency-webservice