# List of SOAP XML APIs for currency conversion

Tags: api, soap, soapui

In my project there is a need to take two different SOAP APIs which can convert currency. I have searched almost everywhere and I could only find one API:

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

This works perfectly but I want one more SOAP API which has both request and response in XML format. I would be highly obliged if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by `" I want one more SOAP API which has both request and response in XML"`?

Comment: @Rao: I meant I wanted an API which is in XML format.  I would be glad if you could help me out.

Comment: Sorry, you just repeated the same without clarifying what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want another SOAP API for currency conversion apart from one mentioned above.

Comment: what do you mean by other SOAP API?

Comment: why do you another one when there is one? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my project there is a need to use two different types of API which would do the currency conversion. That's why I want another one.

Comment: check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873873/realtime-currency-webservice

Comment: Thanks, but these are REST APIs but I want SOAP API.